# I have a XPath reference to an element. But I can not put the variable inside the XPath

Tags: vba, xpath

I am working on a web form flling project in VBA. I can refer to an element through XPath. It functions properly. But If i put a variable inside the XPath and try to refer to the variable I fail.

I have tried to put two double quotes but it did not respond. Then i tried putting "\k\" but it gave result "Type mismatch"

```html
k = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data sheet").Range("A2").Text
bot.FindElementByXPath("//td[contains(text(),'""k""')]/following-sibling::td[5]/input").SendKeys "56"
```

Any one to solve the problem. Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below.

```
k = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data sheet").Range("A2").Value
bot.FindElementByXPath("//td[contains(text(),'" & k  &"')]/following-sibling::td[5]/input").SendKeys "56"
```

Comment: I am getting massage " Expected: list seperator or ) "

Comment: Are you sure the value of `k` is string? should you use `.Value` method rather `.text`? Try printing the `k` value before findelement line.

Comment: Thanx  . I have changed the value from text to value and it worked. Thanx again.